# Simple codon-to-amino acid hash in R

Tags: r, hash, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I want to create an R script in which I have a hash table that I can look up a codon and get its associated amino acid. For example,

```
library(hash)

hashTable <- hash(...) #insert all codon-to-amino acid pairs
hashTable['TTT']
```

will return

```
[1] Phe
```

Does anyone know how I would do this? Or maybe a package (Bioconductor?) I can install that would make this easier?

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to implement this with a has table? iirc there aren't that many amino acid, codon pairs. Do you just want a table look where you put in a codon and get back the associated amino acid?

Comment: @AronBoettcher I just figured it made sense...the keys as the codon and the values as the amino acids. But yes, that's what I want.

Comment: It's pretty easy to use a character vector with name-value pairings for vectorized lookup. myhash <- c("TTT" = "M", "TTA"="else"); myhash[c("TTT", "TAA", "TTA")]

Comment: I mean, we aren't iterating over 10^14th long vector here. There is no need to bring hash tables into play when R doesn't natively, support them. Even calling a library is a little ridiculous in this example considering there are only a tiny handful of things we are trying to find. grep() over a list does the job very well. It took me less time to write a function to do it than it would have for me to find a library with a similar function.

Comment: I think that if you look into the underpinnings of R's lookup algorithm for named vectors you will find that it is hashed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is almost certainly a pre-existing solution for this problem. One possibility is Bioconductor's [Biostrings](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html), *e.g.*:

```
library(Biostrings)
GENETIC_CODE[["ATG"]]
[1] "M"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because why use hashtables?

```
acidLookup<-function(x){
  acids<-c("Isoleucine","Leucine","Valine","Phenylalanine","Methionine","Cysteine","Alanine","Glycine","Proline","Threonine","Serine",
         "Tyrosine","Tryptophan","Glutamine","Asparagine","Histidine","Glutamic acid","Aspartic acid","Lysine","Arginine","Stop codons")
  slc<-c("I","L","V","F","M","C","A","G","P","T","S","Y","W","Q","N","H","E","D","K","R","Stop")
  codon<-c("ATT, ATC, ATA","CTT, CTC, CTA, CTG, TTA, TTG","GTT, GTC, GTA, GTG","TTT, TTC","ATG","TGT, TGC",
         "GCT, GCC, GCA, GCG","GGT, GGC, GGA, GGG","CCT, CCC, CCA, CCG","ACT, ACC, ACA, ACG","TCT, TCC, TCA, TCG, AGT, AGC",
         "TAT, TAC","TGG","CAA, CAG","AAT, AAC","CAT, CAC","GAA, GAG","GAT, GAC","AAA, AAG","CGT, CGC, CGA, CGG, AGA, AGG","TAA, TAG, TGA")

  codon.list<-strsplit(codon,",")

  data.frame(acid=acids[grep(x,codon.list)],slc=slc[grep(x,codon.list)],codons=codon[grep(x,codon.list)])
}

acidLookup("ATA")

        acid slc        codons
1 Isoleucine   I ATT, ATC, ATA
```

Comment: Also, I just grabbed those amino acid/ codon pairings of some rando website. On you to check that they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use a specific hash table implementation. If [Biostrings](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) isn't sufficient, the standard *names* notation used in vectors/lists for base R should work:

```
aaCodes <- character(0);
aaCodes["ATG"] <- "Ile";
aaCodes["UGA"] <- "Trp";
aaCodes[c("CTC","AGG")] <- c("Leu","Ser");

> names(aaCodes)
[1] "ATG" "UGA" "CTC" "AGG"

> aaCodes[c("ATG","ATG","CTC","UGA")]
  ATG   ATG   CTC   UGA
"Ile" "Ile" "Leu" "Trp"

> substring("ATGATGCTCUGA",0:3*3+1,0:3*3+3)
[1] "ATG" "ATG" "CTC" "UGA"

> aaCodes[substring("ATGATGCTCUGA",0:3*3+1,0:3*3+3)]
  ATG   ATG   CTC   UGA 
"Ile" "Ile" "Leu" "Trp"
```

This won't show R's internal hash value that is used for each string, but it doesn't seem like this question is asking for that.